# Source for mid winter vacation

Tags: torah-study, employment, tu-bishvat

I have heard that there is a Sefer published 300-400 years ago which indicates that the (Melamdim) Torah teachers would be off on Chamisha Asar B'Shevat in order to rejuvenate. Anyone know where this can be found?

Comment: One day a year? Wow. Yeridath HaDoroth.

Comment: @SethJ Bein Hazmanim is a relatively new concept. The SA HaRav in Hilchos Talmud Torah seemed to have left this one out ;). Ask R' Tzvi Meir Zilberger about Bein Hazmanim.

Comment: See here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16073&st=&pgnum=197&hilite= in the left column on the bottom and continued on the next page.

Answer (score 5):

[Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Purim 2:8:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&st=&pgnum=56) mentions this in the name of [Minhagei Vermasia](http://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/he/associated-publications/48-vermaysa) 211 that on the 15th of Shevat the children would not go learn with their Rabbeim.